# I have a dataframe in r and i have to do a filtering (not a simple count or sum) on groups of ids

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 3 fields (ID, Date, alue) and for each ID i want the row that has the minimum date between all the rows that has date bigger than the row with the biggest date with Value == 0 and == 2. I don't know if it is clear, but i think that with example below it will be.

To be more precise my dataframe looks like:

```
ID       Date     Value
1     19960708      3
1     19960901      2
1     19960916      3
1     19970901      0
1     19971001      3
1     19971231      3
1     19980101      3
2     19900806      3
2     19901215      3
2     19910629      0
2     19911007      3
2     19911201      3
2     19990901      3
2     20001001      3
```

I would like to have as output:

```
ID     Date       Value
1     19971001      3
2     19911007      3
```

This output is because for the ID 1 the biggest date with value == 0 is 19970901. Therefore i'm taking the minumin of the values bigger than 19970901.
Same thing for the ID 2.

I'm trying to use dplyr for filtering the dataframe but i don't have the output that i want. Below the code that i'm using:

```
  df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(DATE > max(df[VALUE==0 | VALUE==2,]$DATE)) %>%
    filter(DATE == min(DATE))
```

The output of this is not the one that i'm expecting because it works for the first ID, but then it uses that date for the comparisons in the others IDs.
As output i have:

```
ID     Date       Value
1     19971001      3
2     19990901      3
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: what if there are no 0 and 2 for a particular ID?

Comment: It is not possible! I will have always at least one 0 or 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify again the df in in the first filtering call:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Date > max(Date[Value == 0 | Value == 2])) %>%
  filter(Date == min(Date))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
#      ID     Date Value
#   <int>    <int> <int>
# 1     1 19971001     3
# 2     2 19911007     3
```

Comment: Perfect, it is precisely what i need!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution:

```
fun1 <- function(data, var = "Value", afterMax = c(0,2), findMin = 3) {
    max_id <- max(which(data[[var]] %in% afterMax))
    tmp    <- which(  data[[var]] %in% findMin )
    min_id <- min(tmp[tmp>max_id])
    return(data[min_id,])
}

setDT(df1)[,fun1(.SD),by="ID"]
```

result:

```
#   ID     Date Value
#1:  1 19971001     3
#2:  2 19911007     3
```

---

For a `dplyr` solution use

```
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% do(.,fun1(.))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

#ensure that df is sorted in ascending by ID and Date
setorder(df, ID, Date)

df[df[, .I[max(which(Value==0 | Value==2)) + 1L], by=.(ID)]$V1]
```

output:

```
   ID     Date Value
1:  1 19960916     3
2:  2 19911007     3
```

With the above approach, if there are IDs with no 0 or 2, a row with all columns filled with NAs will appear for that ID. Hence, if you want to see the ID to show NA for all other columns except ID column, you can use this:

```
setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, rn := as.integer(rn)]
setorder(df1, ID, Date)
df1[df1[, .(rn=.I[max(which(Value==0 | Value==2)) + 1L]), by=.(ID)], on=.(ID, rn)][, 
    rn := NULL]
```

output:

```
   ID     Date Value
1:  1 19971001     3
2:  2 19911007     3
3:  3       NA    NA
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID       Date     Value
1     19960708      3
1     19960901      2
1     19960916      3
1     19970901      0
1     19971001      3
1     19971231      3
1     19980101      3
2     19900806      3
2     19901215      3
2     19910629      0
2     19911007      3
2     19911201      3
2     19990901      3
2     20001001      3", header=TRUE)

df1 <- read.table(text="ID       Date     Value
1     19960708      3
1     19960901      2
1     19960916      3
1     19970901      0
1     19971001      3
1     19971231      3
1     19980101      3
2     19900806      3
2     19901215      3
2     19910629      0
2     19911007      3
2     19911201      3
2     19990901      3
2     20001001      3
3     19990901      3
3     20001001      3", header=TRUE)
```